# Can I create a data file in Python and import it to other python files

Tags: python

I have created a python file that consists some data .
I m able to import this data file to a different python file , but my concern is that I can import only one variable at a time and not all the variables at once.

```
from sourcefilename import RequiredVariable
```

I want to import and use all the variables in one call . Is that possible.

Comment: `from sourcefilename import RequiredVariable, OtherVariable, …`

Comment: Also if you are sure you want to import everything from that file, you can use `from sourcefile import *`. But note that this is not a clean code practise and should be generally avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sourcefilename import *
```

This is really not recommended, though. It lets you imports (essentially, execute) any arbitrary code from the module `sourcefilename`, and then simply copy all global names from that module into your module (overwriting anything previously defined in your module). You should use it only if you can be very certain of the exact data structure that goes into `sourcefilename`. However, if that is the case, you may as well use a more conventional method for storing data, like **JSON** or **pickle**.